# How to unit test a project without mocking but by using database?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mocking

We have developed an application using razor view, c#, MVC3, .net 4.0. We would like to unit test a controller without mocking. Our requirement is: The Repository methods need to be called and executed and the database is to be used for testing. Kindly, provide some solution.

Comment: Such tests are not normally called "unit tests" but rater integration tests. Is there a particular reason why you need your resulting test to be called "unit tests"?

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but you can wrap your test methods in a transaction, then roll back the transaction before the test ends.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests tend not to use such external resources as databases or connection to remote servers. That's why mocks are for.

I believe that sometimes it may be useful to have tests accessing such resources. (but let's call them... acceptance test? or integration tests - just to make difference between those and classic unit tests).

Take a look at [MBUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) testing framework (very similar to nUnit) which allows you to have it done quite easy, at it allows automatic rolling-back of all the changes to the database (so you won't end up restoring your db to its 'clean' state every time you want to run your tests). Have a look at this blog post that describes it in details: http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/01/mbunit-24-rollback-rollback2-and.html

Other approach is to have a special database and generate data - i.e. generate new user ids names etc. every time bunch of test are run. Please note that in this approach it may happen that database will need to be clean from time to time (collision on some values like names, it may also not be possible to test some scenarios with db which is already populated with some data).

Both approaches assume that db schema does not change. If db schema changes - it will involve some work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is called an Integration test and not a Unit test.

This depends on each application but the approach I take for integration tests is:

1. Drop/Create new test database and the schema using a script (happens before each test runs)
2. Run some scripts that put the right data into the database for the specific test
3. Run the test
4. Drop the test database (happens after each test runs)

This ensures that the data is always consistent for testing and also forces you to keep your database scripts up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Don't see the point to this question,

1) That is Integration Testing you are talking about, Not Unit Testing.

2) When running the "Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework", you can always write a TestMethod to use the actual repository instead of mocking stuff, mocking simply replaces the repository with a mock, you can always use the real one.  You just need to configure your db connection string within the test project app config itself etc...really depends on how it is architected.

3) I notice you didn't mention anything about IOC/DI, so I assume you aren't using any, and hence this question.  With IOC/DI, you can always substitute the actual instance you are using when testing, either mock or real, and easily replace your objects from a single entry/code point.  So really, your test project can set up all the dependencies you need.

4) I think MVC comes with the IDependencyResolver, so do have a search on that?

5) IOC container just makes testing easier, is my two cents, else do it the manual way.

Cheers